# Text game. How to use a bag?

Tags: java, class, jcreator

Im wondering how i would go about using a bag in the game im making. The bag is supposed to hold 2 items that can be found in different rooms around the "map" and when both these items are found the game can be completed by finding the boss room. The bag is supposed to be its own java class. And how do i make the player activate these items?

rum4 and rum6 is the item rooms for anyone wondering.

(I dont want anyone to finish this game for me, i just want some help)

//Sorry for the swedish text.

//This is obviously not all of the code but the rest of it is not neccessary.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Spel
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rum start = new Rum("Du är i en mörk och fuktig källare."," En källare. ");
    Rum rum1 = new Rum("Du är mitt i en snöstorm!", "En snöstorm. ");
    Rum rum2 = new Rum("Du hittade ett svärd!", "Ett hus. ");
    Rum rum3 = new Rum("Du gick in i en fälla, slå över 3 för att fly norrut.", "En skog. ");
    Rum rum4 = new Rum("Jaha... här fanns det ingenting.", "En äng. ");

    start.north = rum1;
    start.east = rum2;
    start.south = rum3;

    rum1.south = start;
    rum1.east = rum4;

    rum2.west = start;
    rum2.north = rum4;

    rum3.fälla = new trap();
    rum3.north = start;

    rum4.west = rum1;
    rum4.south = rum2;

    Rum current = start;
    while(true) {
        System.out.println(current);
        System.out.println("Vart vill du gå? (n,s,v,o)");
        char c = new Scanner(System.in).next().charAt(0);
        switch(c) {
            case 'n':
                current = current.north;
                break;
            case 's':
                current = current.south;
                break;
            case 'v':
                current = current.west;
                break;
            case 'o':
                current = current.east;
                break;
        }
        if (current.fälla != null){
            current.fälla.rulla();
        }
    //  if (monster){
    //      System.out.println("Du kan nu döda monsteret");
        if(current == null) {
            System.out.println("Du ramlar av världen och dör †††");
            System.out.println("Försök igen");
            current = start;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to create a class that acts as a bag, and holds the objects that the player finds? What have you tried? Also, the objects, should be special characters in your *map*, like "G" for Gold, right?

Comment: General hints: you shoulb be aware of thinks like "while (true) {do.something} -> Often leads to life/deadlooks and/or other problems. Use some variable instead of "true" like "gameNotFinished". You can use "gameNotFinished" as global variable and change it once your game is done. Also I was wondering why you did not use something like "start.west = anyRum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class Bag with two Items

```
public class Bag {
   Item item1;
   Item item2;
}

public class Item {
   <any item properties here>
}
```

Comment: But how would i make the player activate these items? (Maybe i should have put that in the question)

Comment: I would do it like in real life. Player takes an item from the bag and activates it. So the Bag needs a _take_ method and the Item needs an _activate_ method.

Comment: EpicPandaForce is awesome and all but you did exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

In that case, I believe you need a class for `Item`, and types of items for the specific effects.

```
public abstract class Item {
    public abstract void useItemOn(Entity target);
}

public class Entity {
     private int maxHitPoints;
     private int hitPoints;
     private boolean isDead;
     ...
     public void inflictDamage(int damage) {
         hitPoints -= damage;
         if(hitPoints < 0) {
             this.isDead = true;
         }
     }

     public void heal(int healPoints) {
         hitPoints += healPoints;
         if(hitPoints > maxHitPoints) {
             this.hitPoints = maxHitPoints;
         }
     }
     ...
}

public class Player extends Entity {
    ...
}

public class Enemy extends Entity {
    ...
}

public Bomb extends Item {
    @Override
    public void useItemOn(Entity target) {
        target.inflictDamage(20);
    }
}

public Potion extends Item {
    @Override
    public void useItemOn(Entity target) {
        target.heal(20);
    }
}
```

Then

```
public class Bag {
    private List<Item> items;

    public Bag() {
         this(new ArrayList<Item>());
    }

    public Bag(List<Item> items) {
         this.items = items;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
         return items;
    }
}
```

You can of course use smarter way to store `Item`s to not mix them up, as you still need to figure out if something is a potion or a bomb.

But anyways, using it is simple, you need to take an item from the list, use it on an entity, then remove it from the list if it's a consumable.

Answer (score 1):

Can someone find the boss room before they found the items? If no: how do you prevent it?

What you have to do when using my solution:

1. Create the bag at the begin of the game
2. Whenever one of the items was found: call the setFirstItemFound or setSecondItemFound method.
3. I don't know how you want to enable the boss room, but you can check if i should be findable by using the method "isBothItemsFound()"

Please notice, that this solution only works if there are only two items needed. If later like 10 items needed i would recommend you to make use of a hashTbale, a list or any equal "stacking" classes

```
public class Bag {    
    private static boolean firstItemFound = false;
    private static boolean secondItemFound = false;

    public Bag() {
        super();
        firstItemFound = false;
        secondItemFound = false;
    }
    /* Sets the status to of the first Item to found */
    public static void setFirstItemFound() {
        firstItemFound = true;
    }

    /*  Checks if the first item has been found */
    public static boolean isFirstItemFound() {
        return firstItemFound;
    }

    /* Sets the status to of the second Item to found */
    public static boolean isFSecondItemFound() {
        return secondItemFound;
    }

    /* Checks if the second item has been found */
    public static void setSecondItemFound() {
        secondItemFound = true;
    }

    /* Checks if both items has been found */
    public static boolean isBothItemsFound() {
        boolean bothItemsFound = false;
        if (firstItemFound && secondItemFound){
            bothItemsFound = true;
        }
        return bothItemsFound;
    }

    /* Sets the status to of both Items to not found */
    public static void clearBag() {
        firstItemFound = false;
        secondItemFound = false;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe create some `Player` class to store all player data, and put `Bag` in it to hold items for example in:

`HashMap<String, Item> itemsByName;`

and always check when adding a new item to it if size 2 is not over exceeded.

Comment: I only want a bag class.I dont want to make it too complicated

Comment: I think the lack of structure will just make it *more* complicated. :o